# Share file storage index with multiple open applications in Java

Tags: java, http, file, caching

I'm writing an HTTP Cache library for Java, and I'm trying to use that library in the same application which is started twice. I want to be able to share the cache between those instances.

What is the best solution for this? I also want to be able to write to that same storage, and it should be available for both instances.

Now I have a memory-based index of the files available to the cache, and this is not shareable over multiple VMs. It is serialized between startups, but this won't work for a shared cache.

According to the HTTP Spec, I can't just map files to URIs as there might be a variation of the same payload based on the request. I might, for instance, have a request that varies on the 'accept-language' header: In that case I would have a different file for each subsequent request which specifies a different language.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

First, are you sure you want to write your own cache when there are several around? Things like:

- [ehcache](http://ehcache.sourceforge.net/)
- [jboss cache](http://www.jboss.org/jbosscache/)
- [memcached](http://www.danga.com/memcached/)

The first two are written in Java and the third can be accessed from Java. The first two also handle distributed caching, which is the general case of what you are asking for, I think. When they start up, they look to connect to other members so that they maintain a consistent cache across instances. Changes to one are reflected across instances. They can be set up to connect via multicast or with specific lists of servers specified.

Memcached typically works in a slightly different manner in that it is running externally to the Java processes you are running, so that all Java instances that start up will be talking to a common service. You can set up memcached to work in a distributed manner, but it does so by hashing keys so that the server you want to connect to can be determined by what it is you are looking for.

Doing a true distributed cache with consistent content is very hard to do well, which is why I suggest looking at an existing library. If you want to do it yourself, it would still help to look at those listed to see how they go about it and consider using something like JGroups as your underlying mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look at the [WebDav-Specifications](http://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/). It's an HTTP extension for sharing/editing/storing/versioning resources on a server. There exists an implementation as an [Apache module](http://www.webdav.org/mod_dav/), wich allows you a swift start using them.

So instead of implementing your own cache server implementation, you might be better off with a local Apache + mod-dav instance that is available to both of your applications.

Extra bonus: Since WebDav is a specified protocoll you get the interoperability with lots of tools for free.